# Running same custom domain in different Azure App Services in same region

Tags: azure, dns, azure-appservice

I need to have the same Azure App Service Custom Domain running in different App Services on the same region. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom domians are based in DNS, only one record should be pointing to one App Service, so I think it would not be recommended to have same custom domain in multiple App Services in the same region. Being said that, it works for different regions and it is common to see this deployments for instance behind Traffic Manager or Azure Frontdoor.

In order to do this in the same region is a bit more challenging as the only way is to make sure your App Service goes to a different webspace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan). So basically to make sure it goes to a different webspace you need to create a new Resource Group and a new App service Plan, then you can create the specific App Service and add the custom domain. In order to make sure they are in different webspaces, check if the Inbound IP is different.